# python.exe has stopped working - svc

Tags: python, crash, scikit-learn, svc

I'm trying to fit a simple SVC model on my dataset. As soon as I run my code, pop-up appears saying python.exe has stopped working.

Here is my code:

```
Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)
svc = SVC()
svc.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
y_pred = svc.predict(Xtest)
print "Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_pred, Ytest)
```

Any help?

P.S. I'm using jupyter notebooks with python 2.7

Comment: Do all the data-sets print correctly? Are `X` and `Y` correctly formed?

Comment: Yes. Both are numpy arrays.

Comment: X = np.asarray(df[['timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']].dropna())

Y = df["activity"].values

Comment: @HussainShahbazKhawaja what versions of python, sklearn do you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a timestamp in my X. I don't know why but by removing that, it started working fine.